How to use RestDocs with the new MockMvcTester API
Is there a way to produce RestDocs with the new (since Boot 3.4) MockMvcTester API? (Not using plain MockMvc?)
I did not find any API on the new fluent style MockMvcTester.
assertThat(
                mockMvc.get()
                        .uri("/api/customer/{id}", customer.customerNumber())

                        .exchange()
        )
                .hasStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                .hasHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyJson().convertTo(CustomerApiDTO.class)
                .isEqualTo(customer)
                 // does not compile anyway
                .consumeWith(document("findByCustomerNumber", // <1>
                        pathParameters(
                                parameterWithName("id")
                                        .description("The public customerNumber")
                        ),
                        responseFields(
                                fieldWithPath("customerNumber")
                                        .description("The unique public ID"),
                                fieldWithPath("firstname")
                                        .description("The first name"),
                                fieldWithPath("lastname")
                                        .description("The last name")
                        )
                ));


You should use apply(ResultHandler) to perform the REST documentation:
assertThat(
    mockMvc.get()
        .uri("/api/customer/{id}", customer.customerNumber())
        .exchange()
)
.hasStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
.hasHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
.bodyJson().convertTo(CustomerApiDTO.class)
.isEqualTo(customer)
.apply(document("findByCustomerNumber", // <1>
    pathParameters(
        parameterWithName("id")
            .description("The public customerNumber")
    ),
    responseFields(
        fieldWithPath("customerNumber")
            .description("The unique public ID"),
        fieldWithPath("firstname")
            .description("The first name"),
        fieldWithPath("lastname")
            .description("The last name")
    )
));


Thanks for helping me with that. I could make it compile, but now it fails like:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: urlTemplate not found. If you are using MockMvc did you use RestDocumentationRequestBuilders to build the request?

`

Unfortunately, there's a limitation with documenting path parameters at the moment. It will be addressed by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/939.
